# How to give user a default password only for the first time user installs the app?

Tags: android, authentication, passwords

I created an app where the user has to login with a password and he can change the password later after he logged in.

But of course he can not have a password when he just installed the app. Is there a way where I can give the user a default password (e.g. "0000) that he can only type in once?

Answer (score 2):

Use `SharedPreferences`, it will take a boolean value lets say Boolean isFirstTime, for default keep it true, and in your loginActivity set default password as soon as user clicks login button, make Boolean value isFirstTime false and commit change to shared preferences, and apply the check in onCreate

```
if(!isFirstTime){
   // do not set Password
}
else{
  // set default password
}
```